# pinescript errorinvalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in ta.highest() and ta.highestbars()

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

referring to the code below
plotting temp1 gives the error whereas plotting temp2 plottest OK
??? any suggestions

```
//@version=5
indicator("HighBar Test", overlay=false)

var temp1 = 0
var temp2 = 0
var length_1 = 0
var length_2 = 0
length_1 := bar_index - bar_index[50]
length_2 := 50

// eample 1
temp1 := ta.highestbars(length_1)
//plot(temp1)

// example 2
temp2 := ta.highestbars(length_2)
plot(temp2)

plot(length_2)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime error indicates on the issue with the ta.highestbars() function's length= argument value, which should be an integer value above zero.

[image]

During the first 49 bars on the chart, the `bar_index[50]` call would return **na**, as the reference is not existing yet, hence the `bar_index - na == na`, note that math operators do not support calculations with **na** values. You can protect it using the built-in `nz()` function with replacement:

```
//@version=5
indicator("HighBar Test", overlay=false)
length_1 = bar_index - nz(bar_index[50], -1)
temp1 = ta.highestbars(length_1)
plot(temp1)
```